# Spring Integration | HTTP outbound gateway | Multipart

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, multipartform-data

- Service A receives a file
- Service A performs business logic.
- Service B exposed an HTTP inbound to receive the file and post it
  to S3.
- Service A calling Service B using http outbound gateway.

I am getting an error, unable to find suitable message converter when service A calls Service B using http outbound gateway.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="addHeader" output-channel="s3publishWithHeader">`


<int:header name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data" overwrite="true"/> </int:header-enricher>`

<util:list id="converters">
   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>`



<http:outbound-gateway request-channel="s3publishWithHeader"
                         http-method="POST" url="http://localhost:8090/com/api/upload"
                          extract-request-payload="true" message-converters="converters"
   ></http:outbound-gateway>
```

Version of Spring Integration: 4.3.12

Answer (score 3):

When using a `Resource` multipart it seems crucial that this resource has a file name, otherwise I found that the receiving server complains that the part is not present.

The `MultiValueMap` which will become the multipart request body can contain `HttpEntity` parts where you can specify the parts more precisely, e.g. you can specify a file name.

Assuming you have two parts, `request` and `file`, and file is an `InputStreamResource` (which never has a file name), you must define the filename by means of the `Content-Disposition` header. Use the resulting map as outgoing message payload, like so:

```
MultiValueMap payload = new LinkedMultiValueMap();

// some json part named "request"
HttpHeaders requestPartHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestPartHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<ConversionRequest> requestEntity = 
    new HttpEntity<>(requestBean, requestPartHeaders);

// InputStreamResource part named "file"
HttpHeaders fileRequestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

fileRequestHeaders.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("form-data")
        .name("file") // name of the part in the map
        .filename("my-file-name.pdf") // <-- mandatory file name
        .build());

fileRequestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fileMimeType));
HttpEntity<InputStreamResource> fileEntity = 
    new HttpEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(fileOriginalStream),
        fileRequestHeaders);

payload.add("request", requestEntity);
payload.add("file", fileEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify that `Content-Type` header and you don't need to configure custom converters.

Only what you need is a `payload` as `Map<String, Object>`:

```
else if (content instanceof Map) {
        // We need to check separately for MULTIPART as well as URLENCODED simply because
        // MultiValueMap<Object, Object> is actually valid content for serialization
        if (this.isFormData((Map<Object, ?>) content)) {
            if (this.isMultipart((Map<String, ?>) content)) {
                contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
            }
            else {
                contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED;
            }
        }
}
```

Nonetheless you have to show the StackTrace for error because I think there is something with response parsing.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan 
Updated the code and removed the references on Content-Type . Code and stack trace is available in gist.github.com/vssprakash/1629d7fcee4143f227f4bacc262fa6b2

Comment: I would suggest you to consider to represent your file to send as a `byte[]` or `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. Otherwise we have that fallback to the `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for non-conform type of value in the `MultiMap`

Comment: The code quoted by @ArtemBilan is from `AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#resolveContentType`

Comment: Note that `resolveContentType()` is only called if the outgoing message has no contentType header, so you may have to overwrite such a pre-existing contentType header with `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`